# Eloquent find(2) returning wrong record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

`$wire = Wire::find(2)->value('options');
        var_dump($wire);
        die();`

Returns `string(39) "{"note": "wire one", "value": "WIRE 1"}`

These are my 2 database entries.

```
1   {"note": "wire one", "value": "WIRE 1"} WIRE ONE    2017-01-29 01:37:49 2017-01-29 01:37:49
2   {"note": "wire two", "value": "WIRE 2"} WIRE TWO    2017-01-29 01:38:19 2017-01-29 01:38:19
```

Why is find(2) returning value for record #1?

I recognized this in another Laravel app. This was done in a fresh Laravel app.

Comment: `find` is to find a model by its primary key. Is the first column has primary key

Comment: Yes.
CREATE TABLE `wires` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `options` json NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/model-findid-returns-multiple-records

I think the answer is there. Looks like my ->value('options') uses a builder method and reruns the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like elaborating on the find() method with a ->value or ->get runs an entirely new query.

`Wire::find(2)->get();` runs a new query retrieving all models.

`Wire::find(2);` returns model by primary key 2.